# unexpected XML tag issue with Jax Ws client

Tags: jax-ws

I am consuming a vendor web service. Generated the classes using JDK6 wsimport for the vendor WSDL. Now I am trying to invoke the web service using a simple java client class and getting this exception with response.

**unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://www.abcd.com/addressValidation/}validateAddressResponse but found: {}validateAddressResponse**

The vendor says try with Apache Axis generated classes, it works fine. What I noticed is JaxWS automatically appends/binds namespace to each element in request and expecting the namespace in response element also.

The generated Interface is

```
    @WebService(name = "AddressStandardize", targetNamespace = "http://www.abcd.com/addressValidation/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    com.abcd.ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface AddressStandardize {

    @WebMethod(action = "http://www.abcd.com/standardizeAddress")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "validateAddress", targetNamespace = "", className = "com.abcd.ValidateAddress")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "validateAddressResponse", targetNamespace = "", className = "com.abcd.ValidateAddressResponse")
    public void standardizeAddress(
    ...
    ...
    ...
    );
}
```

I guess Jax-WS appending this target namespace to both validateAddress and validateAddressResponse elements.

**How to avoid binding target namespace to validateAddressResponse element so that it wont expect back in response. Please help!**

Jax WS generated request:

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header>
        <ns2:id xmlns:ns2="http://www.abcd.com/addressValidation/">PSA</ns2:id>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:validateAddress xmlns:ns2="http://www.abcd.com/addressValidation/">
            <arg1>
                <addresslineone>126 corbin st</addresslineone>
                <addresslinetwo/>
                <addresslinethree/>
                <city>jersey city</city>
                <state>NJ</state>
                <postalcode/>
                <country/>
                <isocountrycode>US</isocountrycode>
            </arg1>
        </ns2:validateAddress>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Return Response:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xyz="http://www.abcd.com/xyz">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xyz:id>PSA</xyz:id>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <validateAddressResponse xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="addressValidation.xsd">
            <validateAddressReturn>
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </validateAddressReturn>
            <ResponseStatus>
                <StatusCode>SUCCESS</StatusCode>
            </ResponseStatus>
        </validateAddressResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This response is coming with this exception...
unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://www.abcd.com/addressValidation/}validateAddressResponse but found: {}validateAddressResponse

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue, and was unable to find a way to tell JAX-WS not to expect a namespace. However, I was able to work around it by pre-processing the response in a [SOAPHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html) and manually adding a namespace to the XML element (by giving it a new QName that included a namespace declaration).

**MyHandler.java:**

```
public class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) { 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        //Don't intercept outbound messages (SOAP Requests)
        if ((Boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {return true;}

        SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
        try {
            SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
            Iterator<SOAPElement> bodyIterator = body.getChildElements();
            SOAPElement responseElement = bodyIterator.next();
            responseElement.setElementQName(new QName("http://www.theserver.com/cmdb_rel_ci", origGetRecordsResponse.getLocalName(), "cmdb"));
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

Then I just had to add my Handler to the HandlerChain with the following code in my main class, and it worked.

```
Binding binding = ((BindingProvider)port).getBinding();
List<Handler> handlers = binding.getHandlerChain();
handlers.add(new MyHandler());
binding.setHandlerChain(handlers);
```

Comment: ignoring `MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY` fixed my  error, thanks.